# Gmail store single copy of mail for both sender and receiver?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database-design

If I am sending mail from Gmail to other Gmail user does it store single copy or multiple copy of mail for each?

If its saves single copy what if sender delete his email?

I am creating database schema for this kind of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I am sending mail from Gmail to other Gmail user, does it store single copy or multiple copy of mail for each?

We don't know. And it doesn't matter.

> What if sender delete his email?

You can't expect an email to disappear from recepients' inboxes simply because sender deleted it on their end. This is not how email works.

For generic messaging application, when there's no other domains (you control all messages), you can implement such behaviour, if needed. However, some functional requirements of your app may make it very hard. For one-on-one messaging, you can follow advice from Sunil's answer, for example. But what if message has 5 recipients? How many flag columns do you put on messages table? What if message has 200 recipients? Common sense dictates that at least *some* of information must be duplicated for each recipient and, therefore, is shielded from sender's activity (deletion and whatnot).

Answer (score 1):

How does Gmail do it? Who knows? Who cares? The question is what meets YOUR requirements.

If you are building some kind of messaging system where all messages live on a single database, then it makes sense to just have one copy of each message. You have a separate table or tables to link each message to the relevant users. Like you have a "message" table that holds message text, a "user" table that holds information about each user, and a "user-message" table that links users to messages, containing the user id, message id, a field to identify whether this is the sender or the receiver, maybe other data. If a user deletes a message from his mailbox, you delete the user-message record. Perhaps when the last user-message record for a given message is deleted, you then delete the message.

If there's a reason to keep history, records may not really be deleted but instead marked as deleted.